# How do I send items to a gregtech machine only if it is not running?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

So I have an array of gregtech machines (induction furnaces at the moment, but I want to set up rotary macerators, singularity compressors, industrial centrifuges, centrifuge extractors, etc). Each array consists of 8 machines and I have 8 arrays per machine. I want to make sure that if all 8 machines are full then send it to the flow of items to the next array of 8.

I started this project with electric furnaces. That was very convenient because you could just use a gate set to "is running". But that can't be done with the induction furnace.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I get a redstone signal if a machine is running?
2. How do I make items go one way when redstone power is active and another way when redstone power is turned of?

Edit: I would prefer a solution with redstone but it does not have to be with it if it is possible in another way that would be ok to.

Comment: are you ever going to be able to fill up 8 fully heated induction furnaces? Those things are insanely fast

Comment: I know but i'm cooking cobble and other ores so i cant have one array. I want to have a few groops with machines. So i can procces a lot of stuff

Comment: I never tried Automating those furnaces in that way, but what you could try to do is using Buildcraft's structure pipes and gates. Get a signal with diamond gates etc., run it to where you need it with the pipe wire and the structure pipes and turn it into a redstone signal with a simpler gate

Comment: I tried that but the is running is not avaiable for the induction furnace but they are for the electric ones as well as normal macerators, extractors, and compressors but for the gregtech this option on gates is not avaiable

Comment: You do not want to directly connect them, it is enough if you have them next to the oven to check for its contents. I know that it works with blood magic and I would test it myself with ic2, but sadly I have no access to my gaming computer right now :(

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution. I already have setup everything for the furnaces exept the deviders for each array. I really want to get this running. I have to cook 6 crystal chests of cobble